# Is the Borel $\sigma$-Algebra on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ complete?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Why is the Borel $\sigma$-Algebra on a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ said to be incomplete wrt. to the Lebesgue measure?

As I understand a complete measure space contains all subsets of all sets of measure zero from the $\sigma$-Algebra. Any subset of a set with measure zero in the Borel $\sigma$-Algebra of a subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is of dimension $d-1$ which means it is closed, so again measurable.

Comment: I think it's overlapped with say https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575396?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! I think the mistake in your reasoning is "any subset of a set with measure zero must be closed". This is not true - consider for example the measure-zero set $\Bbb R \times \{0\} \subseteq \Bbb R^2$. This has many non-closed subsets - for example, $(0, 1) \times \{0\}$, as well as non-Borel subsets as explained at the link in the above comment. Possibly you're conflating "closed" and "not open".

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I see thank you. But if $d=1$ then any zero set consists of countably many points right? so any subset is a set of measure zero again, right?

Comment: It's not true that any null set in $\Bbb R$ consists of countably many points. The standard example is the Cantor set!

Comment: Can you please define this "dimension" you speak of?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio i meant that in a informal way. What I was saying was if a set has zero volume or zero area then the object must be a hyperplane (so one dimension less). For instance something that has finite volume must be flat ect.

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen So when formulating the standard convergence result of lebesgues dominated convergence theorem in for example $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}, \lambda)$ we also need to impose always that the limit function is measurable? Since we can not guarantee its measurability if the underlying measure space is incomplete.

Comment: I don't think so. A pointwise limit of Borel measurable functions [is automatically Borel](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1327081/473276). For a measure space, "incomplete" doesn't have much to do with "measurability of functions is preserved under limits".